# Select count (*) but for every table in my db

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I'm currently try to connect the tables I have in my database (who's based in "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio") to a Excel file.

I've already connected the name of all the tables, but what I need to do is displaying how many items there are in every single table.

**Like this:**

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvxHz.png)

I did it via

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM [DB_name].[dbo].[DB_table]
```

My question is: is there a way to `SELECT COUNT (*)` for every table in my database with just one SQL command?

I need something like:

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM [MEC-ED].[dbo].[all_Tables]
```

Comment: You can get the *approximate* row count from the system tables. You can't do a `COUNT(*) FROM {Every table}` though, no; you would need 1 `SELECT` statement per table.

Comment: Okay, as i thought, thnks.
Mind me an other question (and if u need example i'm gonna edit the main question)

Comment: If i need to add a new DB_Table, my list in Excel update automatically , but row count doesnt update. Do i have to add a SELECT COUNT (*) manually? or is there a way to add it automatically as the Table_Name?

Comment: I have no idea what the above question has to do about Excel; you're asking about SQL Server here.

Comment: You can add Query command in excel, so i'm asking for excel. Also i added both of the tags so i'm asking for the both of them

Comment: How to get the count for *every* table in a database, and how to consume data from SQL Server in Excel are *completely* different questions, and should be asked as 2 separate questions.

Comment: That come out wrong, i dont know how to express what i need (english is not my first language), so nevermind thanks for the first answer you gave me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT      o.name          AS TableName
            , i.rows        AS NumRows
FROM        dbo.sysobjects o
JOIN        dbo.sysindexes i
ON          o.id = i.id
WHERE       i.indid < 2 
            AND o.type='U'
```

You might want to run this first

```
DBCC UPDATEUSAGE(0) WITH NO_INFOMSGS
```

. . . to get more accurate results.